# Vue.js is not reflecting in laravel project

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.4, bootstrap-vue

I have been trying to use vue.js in my laravel 5.4 cms admin-panel project... i'm trying to create a checkbox with vue.js such that anytime a user tries to reset there password they could either select the checkbox and have an auto_generate password or enter it manually. By selecting the auto_generate password, the password input word become invisible. I'm using vue with bootstrap and it hasn't been responding as if the vue itself is not reflected in the project because anytime i use b-checkbox, its always empty. This is my code...

Create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.manage')

@section('content')
    <div class="flex-container m-t-10">
        <div class="columns m-l-10">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="title m-l-15">Create New Users</h1>
            </div>              
        </div>
        <hr class="m-t-0">

        <form action="{{route('users.store')}}" method="POST">
            {{csrf_field()}}

                <div class="col-lg-offset-0 col-md-12 thumbnail">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="control-label">Name:</label>                       
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" value="{{ old('name')}}" placeholder="Enter your name...">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email:</label>                     
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="{{ old('email')}}" placeholder="Enter your email...">
                        <small>Your email is confidential with us</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="control-label">Password:</label>                       
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" v-if="!auto_password" placeholder="Enter your password...">
                        <b-checkbox name="auto_generate" class="m-t-15" v-model="auto_password">Auto Generate Password</b-checkbox>
                    </div>                                      
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-success fa fa-user-plus pull-right"> Create New User</button>         
            </div>          
        </form>

            <div>
            <a class="btn btn-warning btn-md fa fa-caret-left pull-left" href="{{route('users.index')}}"> Back</a>          
            </div>

</div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        auto_password: true,
    }
    });
  </script>
@endsection
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue ({
    el: '#app'
});
```

node_modules "node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue", its in my app.scss file... maybe i'm not doing it right. App.scss

```
// Variables
@import "variables";

// Font Awesome
@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";

// bootstrap-vue
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue";

// Custom SASS Pages
@import "overrides";
@import "helpers";
@import "manage/";
@import "styles";
```

Please i'll appreciate suggestions of what i'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: `b-checkbox` is part of the `bootstrap-vue` package I'm pretty sure. however, I don't see you using that anymore. Are we missing something?

Comment: Unrelated to your checkbox, you can't do `value="{{ old('email')}}" `. Instead, `:value="old('email')"`

Comment: You seem to have two calls apply `new Vue` to `#app`

Comment: I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93z1f4df/) with your code plugged in. The checkbox works there. It might be good for you to play with it.

Comment: @Roy j, thanks i checked the fiddle... its still not working here, i added another div like you did in the create page to have the #app id, and then deleted it in the layout page, still not working. The checkbox is not yet showing on the page

Comment: Since you're using bootstrap-vue, why not try using the components as intended? Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93z1f4df/5/)

Comment: @btl, the thing is i think bootstrap-vue is not called correctly from node_modules cos its not having any effect on the pages. please help me check my reference to bootstrap-vue in my app.scss. am i getting it right?

Comment: Change it to this `@import "~bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue";`

Comment: @btl, its still not working, the whole password field has even disappeared now. because of the tags <b-form-group> are not recognized

Comment: I dunno, maybe something in one of these is overriding the css?  `// Custom SASS Pages
@import "overrides";
@import "helpers";
@import "manage/";
@import "styles";`

Comment: @btl it isn't cos i've tried removing them and the reloading, and its still the same. i still suspect its the bootstrap-vue not yet recognized. what is the extension of bootstrap-vue meant to be in the node_modules folder?

Comment: `@import "~bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue";` this is exactly as I have it in a project I'm working on right now. Working fine for me. You haven't moved your `app.scss` to another directory have you?

Comment: app.scss is in resources/assets/sass/app.scss. I think that should be the appropriate directory?